# Microsoft Graph 403 when not admin

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am getting 403 for a logged in user with no admin credentials when going for:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
```

It works when I am logged in as an admin.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` is working fine!

I have delegated permissions in Azure and accepted them as an admin via
`prompt=consent` querystring.

```
Read all users' full profiles
Read all groups
Read directory data
Access directory as the signed in user
```

I am getting the token via `this.service.acquireToken(https://graph.microsoft.com)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct workflow but the wrong parameters.

`prompt=consent` is used to force the user to re-consent to the required scopes. Typically you would do this if your scopes have changed and you need user's to re-authorize your application.

This shouldn't be confused with `prompt=admin_consent` which is used when you have scopes that require an Admin's pre-approval prior to standard user's authorizing your application.

You can find more details about `prompt` and other query parameters in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code).

Comment: Yeah man.
After I utilized admin_consent, it started working :)
Big thanks!